# PickerView is Not Showing Selection Separators - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm using `UIPickerView` for gender selection. The problem is, it is not showing selection separators.
Here is my code:

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return pickerDataArr != nil ? 1 : 0
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerDataArr!.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    var label = view as? UILabel

    if label == nil {
        label = UILabel()
    }

    label!.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    label!.textAlignment = .center
    label!.text = pickerDataArr![row]
    return label!
}
```

**Output-**

[image]

I tried these options:
1 Default select first row:

```
pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
```

2 setting property:

```
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true
```

Still no luck...
If anyone has any idea then please share!

Comment: but I want custom view there...

Comment: where did you put this line? `pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true`

Comment: `awakeFromNib` method

Comment: check if your pickerView is != nil in that context that will be the problem

Answer (score 0):

After trying few more options, I've got selections indicators.

Here is the change:

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerDataArr?.count ?? 0
}
```

Everything is same as it was. Somehow, it was related to `numberOfComponents` for picker view.

Even no need of:

```
pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true
```

**Output-**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]**Here is the change**

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return pickerDattaArr.count != 0 ? 1 : 0

}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerDattaArr.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    var label = view as? UILabel
    if label == nil {
        label = UILabel()
    }
    label!.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    label!.textAlignment = .center
    label!.text = pickerDattaArr[row]
    return label!
}
```

Comment: `pickerDataArr` is optional ..!

Comment: here i declare pickerDataArr is constant,


let pickerDattaArr = ["male", "female", "other"]